# How to replace some character from a string in UNIX?

Tags: unix, shell-scripting, aix

I have two string like this...

```
a=[2018:08:22-15:26:18:26182619]
b=[2018:08:22-15:26:18:26182619]
```

And I want to convert 
 `a= 20180911183706376476` 
 `b= 2018082215261826182619`

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: You must include a space around both sides of the `]` and `[`. And when writing shell scripts, it's good to use `shellcheck`.

Comment: Now I want to convert `[2018:08:22-15:26:18:26182619]` to `2018082215261826182619`. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Welcome on the ServerFault. The command can be done with `a="${a//[\[\]]/}"`, this removes all `[` and `]` from the variable `$a`. But it is not really a sysadm task, it is more like a little scripting trick.

Comment: Thanks.Getting error as `ksh: a="${a//[\[\]]/}": bad substitution`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the "**test, [ -- condition evaluation utility**" manpage (accessible using the command *man [* or *man test*), the '-ne' option is used for comparing integers. Use the '=' operator for strings.

> n1 -eq n2     True if the integers n1 and n2 are algebraically equal.
>
> s1 = s2       True if the strings s1 and s2 are identical.

It's probably not a bad idea to quote the strings as well. Make sure to use double (or *soft*) quotes with variables.

```
if [ "$a" = "$b" ]
  then
    #do something
fi
```